# WCF multithread call in c#

Tags: c#, multithreading, wcf, parallel-processing

I am trying to call a `WCF` Service as you can see here:

```
  [ServiceBehavior(UseSynchronizationContext = false,ConcurrencyMode =ConcurrencyMode.Multiple)]

    public class InquiryService : IInquiryService
    {
        private DataContext _ctx;
        private IUserService _userService;
        public InquiryService(DataContext ctx, INajaService najaService, IUserService userService)
        {
            _ctx = ctx;

            _userService = userService;
        }

        public Inquiryview Inquiry(string VisitDatetime, string Plaque)
        {

My service !!!!!
       }

}
```

WCF `webconfig`:

```
 <serviceThrottling maxConcurrentCalls="1000" maxConcurrentSessions="1000" maxConcurrentInstances="1000" />
```

Here is my multithread program to call the service :

```
private async void btnStart_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    btnStart.Content = "Please Wait...";
    btnStart.IsEnabled = false;

    await Task.Run(() =>
    {
        InquiryService service = new InquiryService();
        FinalList = new List<FinalData>();
        var items = Data.GetData(from, to).AsEnumerable();

        start = DateTime.Now;
        Parallel.ForEach(items, new ParallelOptions { MaxDegreeOfParallelism = threadCount }, item =>
         {
             string plaque = Plaque.GeneratePlaque(item.palll);

             var result = service.Inquiry(plaque);
             string serializedResult = new JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(result);

             FinalData finalData = new FinalData()
             {
                 date = result.StartDate,
                 enddate = result.EndDate,
                 log = serializedResult,
                 plaque = plaque
             };

             lock (FinalList)
             {
                 FinalList.Add(finalData);

                 lock (lblCount)
                 {
                     Dispatcher.Invoke(() =>
                     {
                         lblCount.Content = FinalList.Count;
                     });
                 }
             }

             plaque = null;
         });

        end = DateTime.Now;
        duration = end - start;

        Dispatcher.Invoke(() =>
        {
            btnStart.Content = "Insert Data...";
        });

        Data.InsertData(FinalList);
    });

    btnStart.Content = "Start";
    btnStart.IsEnabled = true;

    MessageBox.Show("Service Response Time = " + duration.ToString());
}
```

The class that call the service:

private MemoryStream ms;
    private static readonly string ServiceHostName = "https://****.muservice.ir/InquiryService.svc";

```
public InquiryService()
{
    ms = new MemoryStream();
}

public Result Inquiry(string Plaque)
{
    string result_ = "";
    ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback += (se, cert, chain, sslerror) => { return true; };
    DateTime start;
    DateTime end;
    using (var ClientRequest = new WebClient())
    {
        ClientRequest.Headers["Content-type"] = "application/json";
        ClientRequest.Encoding = Encoding.UTF8;
        NetworkCredential credential1 = new NetworkCredential("1", "1");
        ClientRequest.Credentials = credential1;
        start = DateTime.Now;
        result_ = ClientRequest.
            (ServiceHostName + "/Inquiry/2012-12-28" + "/" + Plaque);
        end = DateTime.Now;
    }

    var javascriptserializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
    Result temp = javascriptserializer.Deserialize<Result>(result_);
    temp.StartDate = start;
    temp.EndDate = end;

    return temp;
}
```

After running the program calls the service correctly(about 100 ms ) ,but after about 1000 requests my request time grows to (8 sec).
I want to know should i change something ?

Comment: Perhaps previous 1000 requests are still processing so next one will need wait until at least one of previous thousand is done.

Comment: are you hosting on IIS? use Profiler to see what is happening, maybe after 1000 requests a lot of unfinished requests have accumulated, it is unlikely that the pipeline would really be able to do 1000 in parallel without any serialization/queueing.

Comment: @dlatikay yes i am using IIS

Comment: @dlatikay so should i change any config setting? in wcf

Comment: @danish so what should i do ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally add this code in config file of client .because the windows has outbound traffic limitation

```
<configuration>  
  <system.net>  
    <connectionManagement>  
      <add address="*" maxconnection="65456”/>  
    </connectionManagement>  
  </system.net>  
</configuration>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this service behavior

```
 [ServiceBehavior(InstanceContextMode = InstanceContextMode.PerCall,
                        ConcurrencyMode = ConcurrencyMode.Multiple)]
```

PerCall instance is recommended for scalability.